# Progressive sql update statement

Tags: t-sql, progressive

6I have two table as follows,
TABLEA:

```
MEMBER_ID   CLIENT_ID   TENTATIVE_ID    TENTATIVE_START_DATE
1   65239   26  6/15/2012
2   63693   NULL    NULL
3   5549    NULL    NULL
4   85452   NULL    NULL
5   77898   11  6/15/2012
6   93119   21  6/15/2012
7   7876    26  6/20/2012
8   27572   26  6/21/2012
9   15524   26  6/21/2012
10  39465   8   6/21/2012
11  10143   26  6/23/2012
12  72828   NULL    NULL
```

TABLE B:

```
TENTATIVE_ID    LAST_AUTO_ASSIGNED_ON
26  6/15/2012
11  6/16/2012
21  6/13/2012
27  6/20/2012
28  6/22/2012
29  6/25/2012
8   6/26/2012
21  6/24/2012
```

Situation is that I need to update the nulls in table A with TENTATIVE_IDs from table B based on minimum LAST_AUTO_ASSIGNED_ON value and every time an id is assigned LAST_AUTO_ASSIGNED_ON is updated with current date time for that id in table B.

In this way we loop though all the tentative ids in table B and assign them to table A.

I am not allowed to use cursor. How could I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have two rows in tableb that have exactly the same data. It's not possible to update the date on just one of those. Is a field missing?

Comment: Also, if you're choosing minimum last auto assigned on date, what criteria to decide between multiple ids with the same minimum date?

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned tentative start date, must that be assigned?

Comment: I have updated the table. Table B was not have duplicates. Tentative start date will be set to getdate().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Tablea 
set tablea.tentative_id = (select top 1 tableb.tentative_id from tableb order by Last_auto_assigned_on, tentative_id), 
Tentative_start_date = getdate() 
from tablea 
where tablea.tentative_id is null

Update tableb 
set last_auto_assigned_on = getdate() 
where tentative_id = (select top 1 tableb.tentative_id from tableb order by Last_auto_assigned_on, tentative_id)

Comment: This has to be done dynamically as we run the query. so for each insert we need to get the latest top id from table B order by minimum Last_auto_assigned_on date.

Comment: Which query? You haven't mentioned any inserts before.

Comment: Use a while exists loop that checks for nulls. Inside the while code block, get the id you want using top 1 and order by. Update that id to  tablea where null and id is the min value in a nested select. Then update table b. that concludes the while code block.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're getting the id from tableb, and the update of tablea should have read "where Memberid = (select top 1 memberid where tentativeid is null order by memberid)"